# Animating growing/shrinking pie using SVG and Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create a growing pie animation using Javascript and SVG embedded in HTML. Input should be percentage and output should be an image. It should animate like this:

[image: image description]

This should work like GUI mouse hold action feedback (user needs long press something). This is also why I can't use GIF animation as the timeout may vary.

I tried to make this in Inkscape and then reverse-engineer the XML but I don't understand it at all. There's a `<path>` node which has property `d` full of gibberish numbers:

```
d="m 250.78761,446.46564 a 28.183382,28.183382 0 0 1 -24.596,27.95413 28.183382,28.183382 0 0 1 -30.85751,-20.83773"
```

I assume these are some points of path. But can't I just make circle and mention percentage of how it's full? How are these points even generated?

This is what I played with:

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  }
svg {
  /** to fit svg in the viewbox**/
  max-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg class="test" viewBox="-20 -20 1000 1000">

    <path
       id="circle4146"
       style="stroke:#61a4ff;stroke-width:15.00000095;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;"
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       sodipodi:cx="140.71873"
       sodipodi:cy="446.46564"
       sodipodi:rx="28.183382"
       sodipodi:ry="28.183382"
       sodipodi:start="0"
       sodipodi:end="1.1720792"
       sodipodi:open="true"
       d="m 168.90212,446.46564 a 28.183382,28.183382 0 0 1 -17.24157,25.97267" />
</svg>
```

The sodipodi stuff is probably used by inkscape, changing it has no effect. I know that the `d` attribute describes complex path. What I really need is for someone to highlight me which points should be moved (using sin and cos I assume) to achieve desired effect.

Also I was unable to adjust the viewport to the circle. Apparently some of the coordinates are not X and Y.

Comment: If you want to understand how path descriptions work, you could always just read the SVG spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  Here I am just calculating what the length of the circumference that the percentage represents. Then I give the circle a stroke dash pattern with that length and a big gap.

```js
setCircleTo(70);

function setCircleTo(percent)
{
    // Get the circle element via the DOM
    var circle = document.getElementById('mycircle');
    // Calculate the circle circumference via the circles 'r' attribute
    var circumference = Math.PI * 2 * circle.r.baseVal.value;
    // Calculate what <percent> of the circumference is
    var adjustedLen = percent * circumference / 100;
    // Set the circle's dashpattern one with a dash that length
    circle.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', adjustedLen+' '+circumference);
}
```

```html
<svg class="test" viewBox="-20 -20 1000 1000">

   <circle id="mycircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" stroke-width="30" fill="none" stroke="#61a4ff"/>

</svg>
```